# UIButton losing text label when navController returns

Tags: ios, uibutton, label

I have a custom UIButton that has the label "Name". When the user clicks this button, it loads another View that displays a list of names, and tapping a name pops this View off, and updates the UIButton with the selected name.

That part works. What doesn't work is if the user *doesn't* select a name from the View, but instead just hits Back. The view is popped off, but now the UIButton text "Name" is removed, and the button text is completely blank.  ***How do I stop the text label from being erased?***

I don't have any code that updates the UIButton label *except* if a row is tapped (didSelectARowAtIndexPath) so I don't understand how the label "Name" is being cleared upon loading a new View. Note that I have three of these buttons w/similar functionality, and only the text of the respective button is erased when tapped - the other two aren't impacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in your `didSelectARowAtIndexPath` method and see where it is being called from. You can read Apple's [Debugging Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html) document for more on using XCode's debugger, or you can just [google for "xcode debugging tutorial"](http://www.google.com/search?q=xcode+debugging+tutorial).

Comment: The use case that is the problem is that I'm not selecting anything in this table, I'm just tapping "Back", and the text label is being cleared. Tapping a item updates the label correctly.

Comment: @beeudoublez: Since you said that the only place in the entire program that updates the label is that function, the best guess is that the function is getting called even when you just hit "Back". If you set a breakpoint in that function and it breaks when you hit "Back", you can examine the backtrace and (hopefully) figure out where it's getting called from. And if it doesn't, you can try to find out where else in your code the label is being updated that you don't know about.

Comment: I see what you're saying - and I put a breakpoint on didSelectRowAtIndexPath: it wasn't triggered by just the View being loaded. I'm wondering if it has to do with the State type, whether Highlighted or Selected is somehow clearing it out....but again I don't have any code that modifies the label

Answer (score 5):

Are you calling Button.titleLabel.text = @"Name"; or the non dot property version of that.  If so that's your problem.  You need to call
    [Button setTitle:@"Name" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; otherwise the title will be lost when the button changes state.  If thats not your issue then please post some code.